# BibTex custom bibliography order?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I need the bibliography in my tex file to be in a custom order. So far I've only found how to sort the bibliography alphabetically or in order of appearance. How may I sort it in a custom order?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you going to reveal what the nature of the custom sorting order is, or are you going to make us guess? (Remark: Virtually all contributors to this site appear to be appallingly bad at guessing and absolutely no good at all at divination.)

Comment: Ok, I thought that was clear, my apologies. By 'custom' sort I mean an oder chosen by me, which is neither alphabetical or in order of appearance. I'd like the bibliography to be sorted in "groups", i.e. from the first position to position A I have one topic, from position A+1 to position B I have another topic and so on so forth. Since I'm citing only some of the bibliography entries, I cannot use the "order of appearance" sorting

Comment: @Mico But there are some exceptions. After nearly 3 years on this site, I am absolutely convinced that *egreg* and *David Carlisle* can read minds!

Comment: @cholo14 Are you willing to switch to biblatex? There might be some useful features.

Comment: @samcarter - Good thing I wrote "virtually all contributors..."! :-)

Comment: Should the groups be labelled in some manner, or will it be obvious to the readers what the groups may be? And, is there any sorting to be done *within* each group (say, alphabetically, by order of first citation, something else entirely)?

Comment: @Mico I need no labeling and the order within each group is irrelevant

Comment: Sorting the entries is only one among many jobs I bibliography style file does. Do you currently have a bib style file you're happy with (other than the fact that it doesn't do the custom sorting thing)?

Comment: @Mico yes, I have a bib file that I'm currently using for the entries in the bibliography. The only issue is the sorting

Comment: @Mico I was using 'unsrt' in order to show the entries in order of appearance but now I need to do what I explained before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't provided a lot of specific information regarding the custom sorting principle(s) you wish to implement. The following solution is therefore  necessarily of the bare-bones, no-frills variety.

- You've indicated (I think) that you're OK with the way that the `unsrt` bibliography style formats various entries of type `@article`, `@book`, etc. I suggest you switch to the `plain` bibliography style. It applies the exact same formatting procedures as `unsrt` does; the main difference is that `unsrt` provides no sorting facility at all.
- Insert the following instruction at the very top of your `bib` file:

  ```
  @preamble{ "\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{} " }
  ```
- Let's label the topics and associated groups of entries `01`, `02`, etc. It's important that they be given numeric labels. The assumption is that all entries labelled `01` should be listed before those with label `02`, and so on.

  If you have more than 100 but fewer than 1000 groups, just switch the labelling system to `001`, `002`, etc.
- For all entries that belong to topic `01`, change the author field as follows: add the prefix `\noopsort{01}` to the surname of the first author in the `author` field. E.g., if the author field of a given entry that is supposed to belong to group `01` is given by

  ```
  author = "Author, Anna and Zebulon Zingales",
  ```

  change it to

  ```
  author = "\noopsort{01}Author, Anna and Zebulon Zingales",
  ```

  Note: no space between the prefix and the first author's surname.
- Ditto for all remaining entries of type `01` and for all entries that belong to topics `02`, `03`, etc.
- Since you're using a bibliography style that applies sorting, all entries whose first author's surname is prefixed with `01` will be placed before those with prefix `02` which, in turn, will precede those with prefix `03`, etc. Here's why it's crucial to use numeric labels: in the ASCII table, the numerals `0` thru `9` occur before uppercase and lowercase letters. Thus, the numeric prefixes take precedence over the subsequent letters that make up the authors' names.

  For instance, the entry with author field `"\noopsort{01}Author, Anna and Zebulon Zingales"` will be placed before an entry with author field `"\noopsort{02}Aardvark, Alison and Sean Sheep"`.

  A side effect, which is presumably not unwelcome, is that *within* each group/topic the entries will be sorted alphabetically. Finally, because `\noopsort` doesn't "do anything" with its argument as far as LaTeX is concerned, the labels won't show up in the typeset bibliography.
- Then, rerun LaTeX -- you did change the argument of `\bibliographystyle` from `unsrt` to `plain`, right? -- BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Comment: Incidentally, this solution method works not only with the `plain` bibliography style. Indeed, it works with *any* bibliography style that performs alphabetical sorting.

Comment: @Servaes - Do please state which part of my answer "does not work." For sure, the code I provided above works just fine for the OP's use case. If my answer "does not work" for *your* use case, it must be because your use case is materially different from the OP's. If you don't reveal what your use case is, it's not possible to help you meaningfully, is it?

Comment: @Servaes - My answer as well as the original query were unambiguously marked as pertaining to BibTeX. I made no claim whatsoever that my answer would work with biblatex (and biber). In a way, I'm neither surprised nor bothered by the fact that my answer doesn't "work" with biblatex.

Comment: @Servaes - I refer explicitly to the `unsrt` bibliography style, and later on to the `plain` bibliography style; such remarks only make sense if BibTeX is in use. The answer was "accepted" by the OP, so clearly it "worked" for that person. As you haven't indicated what exactly you were doing, I simply have no way of diagnosing why the method shown above doesn't "work" for you. But I guess that obtaining meaningful help was never your intention to begin with. Posting a useless remark and casting a downvote are evidently much more satisfying activities. Best wishes. You'll go far.